# Need an alernative to While Loop for simple query using SQL stored procedure or function

Tags: sql-server, while-loop, functional-programming, nested-loops, table-valued-parameters

I have a simple parent / child record set that I currently loop through and display with code on the client that I want to move to a procedure for performance reasons.

This used in a classic .asp web page to create a dynamic html table.

The current logic uses a nested do-while not EOF to pull and concatenate child records into a single column as I am iterating through a main record set

Main record set pulls parent Asset data based on a stored procedure: (pseudo code) 
"RS1 
Select AssetID,field1,field2,field3 from Assets where AssetID = AssetID"

As I am displaying this output I call out to this loop to add a column to the original result set with concatenated values from a proc with the parameter of the AssetID of row being displayed.

```
While not rs1.eof
      sSQL = "EXEC GetAuditDescriptions @AssetID ='" & RS1("AssetID")& "'"
            set AuditRs = conn.execute(sSQL)    
        if not auditRS.EOF then
                auditRS.MoveFirst
                while not(auditRS.EOF)
                    auditDescrs = auditDescrs & auditRS.Fields("audit_text").Value & ", "
                    auditRS.MoveNext                    
                wend                
            end if
            auditRS.Close
```

This creates a single "column" with the concatenated output of a single field in GetAuditDescriptions

Final output is

```
AssetID, Field1,Field2,Field3,[auditDescrs1, auditDescrs2, auditDescrs3]
```

Right now this happens on the client but Id like to create a function to call from my main procedure to just return this concatenated output as a column in my original query on the backend.

I have heard that loops in a stored proc are not a good idea and wanted to know if I can create a table based function to call from my proc to pull these values but I need them returned as a concatenation of each row as a single row single column.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My preference is FOR XML PATH - [see here for examples](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation).

Comment: Aaron-this is great thanks.  I created a table based function based on this solution and got what I needed.

Now I am trying to call this function from my main procedure to add a column with the concatenated results.    The function needs a parameter (@assetID) but I am calling it with a literal as (select field1 from function(audit.assetID) as NewColumn)--   where audit.assetID is a field the select in my proc.    Intellisense shows no problem but the proc will not compile.   If I define the @assetID param and syntax newfunction(@assetID) it compiles. but that's no good either. any ideas?